How to use Switch GM3 in Android with XML, not Compose
I see here is new design for Android Switch https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/components/switch

I like this, but how to use?
Relative article we need Compose for this? Can I use this with XML?
If I try use Switch or SwitchMaterial, I see this Switch. It looks like GM2

But I want to get GM3. How? Thanks!

you can go through this link for material M3 https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Switch.md
